# Count number of bits in a 64-bit (long, big) integer?

Tags: c#, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

I have read through [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023) about 32-bits, but what about 64-bit numbers?  Should I just mask the upper and lower 4 bytes, perform the count on the 32-bits and then add them together?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can find 64 bit version here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight

It is something like this

```
static long NumberOfSetBits(long i)
{
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555);
    i = (i & 0x3333333333333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333);
    return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0F) * 0x101010101010101) >> 56;
}
```

This is a 64 bit version of the code form here [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023)

Using Joshua's suggestion I would transform it into this:

```
static int NumberOfSetBits(ulong i)
{
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555UL);
    i = (i & 0x3333333333333333UL) + ((i >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333UL);
    return (int)(unchecked(((i + (i >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FUL) * 0x101010101010101UL) >> 56);
}
```

**EDIT**: I found a bug while testing 32 bit version. I added missing parentheses. The sum should be done before bitwise &, in the last line

**EDIT2** Added safer version for ulong

Comment: should be unsigned long to avoid being burned

Comment: Operations should be unchecked. Otherwise the multiplication in the last line overflows very easily. But if they are unchecked, I think it works for signed long too. Even if the shift is an arithmetic one, most significant bits are discarded by a bitwise & and subtraction in the first line can overflow silently to the correct result.

Answer (score 10):

A fast (and more portable than using non-standard compiler extensions) way:

```
int bitcout(long long n)
{
   int ret=0;
   while (n!=0)
   {
       n&=(n-1);
       ret++;
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Every time you do a `n&=(n-1)` you eliminate the last set bit in `n`. Thus this takes O(number of set bits) time.

This faster than the O(log n) you would need if you tested every bit - not every bit is set unless the number is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`), thus usually you need far fewer iterations.

Comment: It has less loop than thecoop's `if ((val & 0x1) == 0x1) count++;`

Answer (score 6):

Standard answer in C#:

```
ulong val = //whatever
byte count = 0;

while (val != 0) {
    if ((val & 0x1) == 0x1) count++;
    val >>= 1;
}
```

This shifts `val` right one bit, and increments `count` if the rightmost bit is set. This is a general algorithm that can be used for any length integer.

Answer (score 1):

What about an one liner:

```
BitOperations.PopCount(Mask);
```

Returns the population count (number of bits set) of a mask. Similar in behavior to the x86 instruction POPCNT. Compatible with x64! It uses an intrinsic (built-in instruction of the X86 architecture) to count the number of bits very fast in a 32 bit or 64 bit value.

NOTE: BitOperations.PopCount() is not CLS compliant. Take this under consideration.

Cheers

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.