# Kernel macro for counting bits set

Tags: c, linux-kernel, bit-manipulation, linux-device-driver, device-driver

Is there a standard Linux Kernel bit operation macro, which returns the number of bits set in an unsigned long ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

`hweight_long`

function in `include/linux/bitops.h`

Othwerwise Linux kernel uses `gcc` with GNU extensions and `gcc` also provides these builtins:

> Built-in Function: int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)
>   Returns the number of 1-bits in x.
>
> Built-in Function: int __builtin_popcountl (unsigned long)
>   Similar to __builtin_popcount, except the argument type is unsigned long.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you included C in your tags. You could use `C` code to determine as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709523/1952879)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709523/1952879