# Counting number of bits in an unsigned long

Tags: c

So I've written this function to count the number of bits in a long, which for my purposes includes zeros to the right of the MSB and excludes zeros to its left:

```
int bitCount(unsigned long bits)
{
    int len = 64;
    unsigned long mask = 0x8000000000000000;
    while ((bits & mask) == 0 && len > 0){
        mask >>= 1;
        --len;
    }
    return len;
}
```

This function works fine for me as far as returning a correct answer, but is there a better (faster or otherwise) way to go about doing this?

Comment: some architectures have an intrinsic `__popcnt`.

Comment: A `long` is not guaranteed to have 64 bits!

Comment: Did you search? This is no consulting site.

Comment: Why would you ever count the number of bits in a 64 bit number? The only situation where I ever worried about numbers of bits set was in a _huge_ bit array. And counting the number of bits in a 64 bit number is a very inefficient building block for that.

Comment: On a normal computer with 8-bit bytes, the number of bits of any primitive integer type is `sizeof(type) * 8`.

Comment: As for @Olaf's comment about `long` not always being 64 bits, I suggest you *don't* try running that code on a 32-bit system, *or* in a program built using the Visual C++ compiler (even on a 64-bit system).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of bits in a 64-bit (long, big) integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709430/count-number-of-bits-in-a-64-bit-long-big-integer)

Comment: More generally, the number of bits in any type is `sizeof(type)*CHAR_BIT`, where `CHAR_BIT` is defined in `<limits.h>` and is the (implementation-defined) number of bits in a `char`.

Comment: Your title doesn't match your code... what is it you want to do? It seems you try to find the highest numbered bit being `1`

Comment: just some modifications to the algorithm for 32 bit is needed. This was askedd so many times [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/995714). And what you mean is "counting number of **set** bits", not counting number of bits which is always `sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT`

Comment: That would be any implementation using the Windows-API, not only MSVC (the question is tagged C). And what is the problem using the correct type or at least calculating the width correctly: `sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT`. Ignoring padding bits would be an acceptable compromise.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: To be pedantic: That formula gives the total number of bits reserved for the type, but there might be padding bits (see my comment above, too).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of bits in a `long` type, I suggest you use `ULONG_MAX` from the [`<limits.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) header file, and use the right shift operator `>>` to count the number of one-bits. This way you don't have to actually know the number of bits beforehand.

Something like

```
unsigned long value = ULONG_MAX;
unsigned count = 1;

while (value >>= 1)
    ++count;
```

This works because the right shift fills up with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer for the number of bits in any type is `CHAR_BIT*sizeof(type)`.   `CHAR_BIT`, defined in `<limits.h>` is the (implementation-defined) number of bits in a `char`.   `sizeof(type)` is specified in a way that yields the number of `char`s used to represent the type (i.e. `sizeof(char)` is `1`).

Answer (score 0):

The solutions the other guys proposed are very nice and probably the shortest to write and remain understandable. Another straight forward approach would be something like this

```
int bitCountLinear(long int n) {
    int len = sizeof(long int)*8;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) 
        if ((1UL<<i) > (unsigned long int)n) 
            return i;
    return len; 
}
```

The rest might get a bit extreme but I gave it a try so I'll share it.
I suspected that there might be arguably faster methods of doing this. eg Using binary search (even though a length of 64bits is extremely small). So I gave it a quick try for you and for the fun of it.

```
union long_ing_family {
    unsigned long int uli;
    long int li;
};

int bitCountLogN(long int num) {
    union long_ing_family lif;
    lif.li = num;
    unsigned long int n = lif.uli;
    int res;
    int len = sizeof(long int)*8-1;
    int max = len;
    int min = 0;

    if (n == 0) return 0;
    do {
        res = (min + max) / 2;
        if (n < 1UL<<res)
            max = res - 1;
        else if (n >= (1UL<<(res+1)))
            min = res + 1;
        else
            return res+1;
    } while (min < max);

    return min+1;   // or max+1
}
```

I then timed both to see if they have any interesting differences...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define REPS 10000000

int bitCountLinear(long int n);
int bitCountLogN(long int num);
unsigned long int timestamp_start(void);
unsigned long int timestamp_stop(void);
union long_ing_family;

int main(void) {

    long int n;
    long int begin, end;
    long int begin_Lin, end_Lin;
    long int begin_Log, end_Log;

    begin_Lin = 0;
    end_Lin = 0;
    begin_Log = 0;
    end_Log = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++i) {
        begin_Lin += timestamp_start();
        bitCountLinear(i);
        end_Lin += timestamp_stop();
    }
    printf("Linear: %lu\n", (end_Lin-begin_Lin)/REPS);

    for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++i) {
        begin_Log += timestamp_start();
        bitCountLogN(i);
        end_Log += timestamp_stop();
    }
    printf("Log(n): %lu\n", (end_Log-begin_Log)/REPS);

}

unsigned long int timestamp_start(void) {
    unsigned int cycles_low;
    unsigned int cycles_high;
    asm volatile ("CPUID\n\t"
        "RDTSCP\n\t"
        "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low)::"%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
    return ((unsigned long int)cycles_high << 32) | cycles_low;
}

unsigned long int timestamp_stop(void) {
    unsigned int cycles_low;
    unsigned int cycles_high;
    asm volatile ("RDTSCP\n\t"
        "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %1\n\t"
        "CPUID\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low)::"%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
    return ((unsigned long int)cycles_high << 32) | cycles_low;
}
```

...and not surprisingly they didn't.
On my machine I'll get numbers like
Linear: 228
Log(n): 224
Which are not considered to be different assuming a lot of background noise.

Edit:
I realized that I only tested the fastest solutions for the Linear approach so changing the function inputs to

```
bitCountLinear(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF-i);
```

and

```
bitCountLogN(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF-i);
```

On my machine I'll get numbers like
Linear: 415
Log(n): 269
Which is clearly a win for the Log(n) method. I didn't expect to see a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of bit 1 first:

```c
int bitCount(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long tmp;
    tmp = n - ((n >> 1) & 0x7777777777777777)
            - ((n >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333)
            - ((n >> 3) & 0x1111111111111111);
    tmp = (tmp + (tmp >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F;
    return 64 - tmp % 255;  // temp % 255 is number of bit 1
}
```

Take a look at the MIT HAKMEM Count.