# Error creating new stored function in C to count set bits in BIGINT

Tags: postgresql

System Details:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03"
POSTGRESVERSION="9.4.6"
```

I want to create a stored function in c to count the number of bits that are set in a bigint, so using this algorithm:

[Count number of bits in a 64-bit (long, big) integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709430/count-number-of-bits-in-a-64-bit-long-big-integer/2709523)

I wrote this code:

```
#include "/usr/include/pgsql92/server/postgres.h"

#ifdef
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

int bitcardinality(unsigned long i){
        i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555UL);
        i = (i & 0x3333333333333333UL) + ((i >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333UL);
        return (int) (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FUL) * 0x101010101010101UL) >> 56;
}
```

and compiled it as such:
    sudo cc -fpic -c ~/landingzone/cfuncts/bitcardinality.c
    sudo cc -shared -o ~/landingzone/cfuncts/bitcardinality.so ~/landingzone/cfuncts/bitcardinality.o

and placed the so in the $libdir folder, using this guide:
https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/aw_pgsql_book/node170.html

I created this function creation statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION bitcardinality(BIGINT bitstring)
  RETURNS BIGINT
AS '$libdir/bitcardinality.so'
LANGUAGE 'C';
```

Which gives this error:

```
ERROR: incompatible library "/usr/lib64/pgsql92/bitcardinality.so": missing magic block HINT: Extension libraries are required to use the PG_MODULE_MAGIC macro.
```

I even tried removing the #ifdef#endif but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the documentation on `PG_MODULE_MAGIC`:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-c.html

It looks like the correct invocation is

```
#include "fmgr.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#else
#error "PG_MODULE_MAGIC wasn't defined!"
#endif
```

I'm surprised that what you wrote (without the identifier after `#ifdef`) would even be accepted by a compiler. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Thanks I seemed to have overlooked that fmgr.h was needed, the changes you suggested fixed my issues and the stored procedure is working. I was using whichever c compiler was installed on the aws ec2 instance. Haha I can't believe I made such a silly mistake maybe I should sleep now. Thanks a lot!